# Нумерация строк при чтении файла

Tags: java

Программа считывает текст из определённого файла.

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines("path", StandartCharsets.UTF8);
for(String lines:source){
```

Далее идёт регулярное выражение, которое находит определённые строки из файла. Как сделать нумерацию каждой строки при чтении и под конец вывести найденные регуляркой строки в коносоль вместе с номером строки?

Comment: Читать не в список, а в массив. Потом, при переборе элементов, индекс в массиве (+1) и будет номером строки.

Comment: @PinkTux чем индекс в массиве "кошернее" индекса в списке?

Comment: @Russtam, странный вопрос. Очевидно, это зависит от контекста применения. Вариантов масса, где-то так лучше, где-то эдак, а где-то совсем по-другому... Во всяком случае индекс для массива - более естественная сущность, чем индекс для списка.

Comment: @PinkTux ну контекст нам известен, и даже если не обращать внимание на то, что переделка примера чтобы там был массив строк, его усложнит, тот факт что есть массив строк ничем не поможет решению вопроса. Т.к. то что вы итерируете список или массив - разницы нет, индекса у вас не будет. Нужно foreach менять на обычный цикл или заводить счетчик. Поэтому ваше предложение читать в массив, вместо списка - не имеет смысла.

Comment: @Russtam, да на здоровье. Можете делать так, как вам удобней, разрешаю.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for(int i=0; i<lines.size(); i++){
// i = номер строк 
lines.get(i)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

list.index0f(String s)
Строка у вас есть, получите индекс тип int
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object)

Comment: При большом количестве элементов будет медленно работать + если есть одинаковые строки, то всегда будет индекс первой строки.